# Spring Data JPA Set-Up: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'

Tags: spring, jpa

I am having an issue setting up Spring Data JPA. I am trying to set it up without using Maven or Gradle but I received this exception upon dynamic web project publish:

Exception message:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'jpa:repositories'

Background:

- Spring Version: 3.2
- File I am editing: applicationContext.xml

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

...

<jpa:repositories base-package="mypackage.common.service"/>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Is there a problem with name spacing or were there Spring Data JPA specific JAR files I should be including that are not part of the Spring 3.2 core?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

and it should work.